# Prestashop send mail attachment pdf from html2pdf

Tags: php, email, pdf, prestashop, html2pdf

Everything is in the title, but to be more precise :

I made an override of Cart.php, in a function i'd like to send a mail with a pdf generated as an attachment.

```
    $file_attachement['content'] = $voucher->output("useless.pdf", 'E');
    $file_attachement['name'] = 'Voucher.pdf';
    $file_attachement['mime'] = 'application/pdf';

    Mail::Send(
        (int)Context::getContext()->language->id,
        'voucherSend',
        "blabla.",
        array(),
        $customer->email,
        $customer->firstname.' '.$customer->lastname,
        $file_attachement,
        null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_
    );
```

(Where `$voucher` is generated via html2pdf)

The mail is sent, but with no attachment unfortunately. However if I change the output option from `E` to `I`, supposed to send the pdf directly to the user browser, it works like a charm...

I really don't understand where am I wrong, and if...

Comment: Are you sure that $file_attachment should be the seventh parameter?

Comment: You're right... don't no why I put it in 7th, should be in 9th...
I change it and I come back

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Tools::file_get_contents('useless.pdf') instead of $voucher->output, and check whether you send this data in right place

Comment: Actually pretty sure it won't works, `useless.pdf` do not exists, in case the 2nd parameter of output is `E` the first parameter is ignored. The file is never created, I only ask to `output` to render the pdf in a mime-type string..

Comment: Ok, then. Can you be a little bit specific? What is the $voucher object? And do you create your own method in the override or override existing one?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to precise it. Post Edited ;)